# Java: what is this datastruct called?

Tags: java

I want to have something like `MOTIVE { GET_PLAYER, GET_FLAG }`.

And in my object, I want something like

```
this.motive = MOTIVE.GET_PLAYER
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are talking about [`enum`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: Not an `Enum` but an `enum`. Actually, both can be used but I prefer `enum` if the Java version is high enough (released no more than 5 years ago or so:)

Comment: same answer here, with more info but still lesser points :(   , Captcha blocked me :-(

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?

```
/**
 * Don't use caps for a "class" name :)
 */
public enum Motive {
  GET_PLAYER,
  GET_FLAG;

}
```

or (with extra fields):

```
/**
 * Don't use caps for a "class" name :)
 */
public enum Motive {
  GET_PLAYER("Assessination Quest"),
  GET_FLAG("Capture the Flag PvP");

  private Motive(final String desc) {
     this.description = desc;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  private final String description;
}
```

usage:

```
public final class MyClass {
    private Motive motive;

    public MyClass(final Motive motive) {
        this.motive = motive;
    }  
}
```

Also consider a Motive.UNKNOWN as a default case to which you can initialize fields, so you don't get possible nulls.

And switch statements can switch on enums!

One concern: You cannot compile the enum class, compile the enum-using class, change the enum class (and compile it again) and expect it to work. enums are kind-of inlined at compile time; the compiler is allowed to use in the enum-using class hard-coded "ordinals" of the enums. Always recompile both enum classes and enum-using classes so they stay in sync,

Answer (score 1):

enum  [examples](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) & [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)